# How can I use a look-up wizard in a query in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am making a program for bank transactions *(homework task from teacher at school)*

I want to enter some data into my `tb_transactions` table, so a query is the best option.

```
 INSERT INTO tb_Transactions ( [Transaction], Account, [Date], 
 Details, Category, [Transaction Type], Amount )
 SELECT [Enter Transaction Number] AS Expr1, [Enter Account Type] AS Expr2, 
 [Enter Date] AS Expr3, [Enter Details (up to 45 characters)] AS Expr4, 
 [Enter Category] AS Expr5, [Enter Transaction Type (C or D)] AS Expr6, 
 [Enter Amount] AS Expr7
 FROM tb_Transactions;
```

So I get 7 input boxes for each field data entry.

---

MY QUESTION:
`Account` and `Category` and `Transaction` have lookup wizards as in:

Account:  `Cheque`, `Savings`

Category: `Salary`, `Miscellaneous`, `Food/Groceries`, `Car/Travel`, `Clothing`, `Entertainment`

Transaction: `C`, `D`

But in the inputbox, obviously I have to type it. But is there a way to still use the listboxes I made?

Comment: You should be using your listboxes, not query parameters. Can you explain a little more about your form?

Comment: Create form with `tb_Transactions` as Recordsource and you will be able to add new records without any code

Comment: @SergeyS.- I am new novice, just learning SQL and MS-ACCESS. I am sorry but i do not understand

Comment: @ChristopherD. - There is no form. The query runs directly from the menubar on the left of my screen. It shows me an inputbox for each field, one at a time, but I don't want an inputbox, I want to be able to still use my look-up wizard

Comment: Well, if you're not using a form, that's the answer right there for you. Use a form. Creating one can be as simple as clicking on the table, going to the create tab, and pressing "Form"

Comment: Then the query can reference the controls on form as parameters.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Okay, I can do that, but for this school project my teacher said he doesn't want me to use a form. However, it seems that what I am trying to do can't be done, so if you post that as an answer I'll accept it, and thanks for the help.

Comment: See [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Never ask one without saying so!